# Is there a way to hack JSFiddle if not how can it be?

Tags: javascript, security, ide, jsfiddle

I know the title seems a little bit suspicious but I don't want to harm JSFiddle at all.

I'm creating an IDE and I'm using an evil `eval()` function multiple times in order to compile user's codes (there's multiple pages) on client side.
Only problem is I'm using Fabric.js and have a `canvas` global variable that user can easily set to `null` and then my IDE doesn't work anymore the way it should.
(User needs to have access in my project to the canvas context or whatever you call it).

I've tried setting `window` variable to `null` in JSFiddle unfortunately it's a readonly variable.
So I'm just asking myself is there any global variable JSFiddle uses that can be accessed via scripting in their IDE and mess up with their IDE's behaviour locally and if not how do they manage to do that?

So in a certain manner I'm wondering if it's acceptable to have such leaks in an online editor as it's only messing with it on local way considering it's user responsability to share (code can be shared like in JSFiddle) a working project when executing (always client/side).

Don't hesitate to make me edit my post if unclear to you.